# Connection issue when connection to MySQL running on AWS EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh

I was trying to connect using SQL workbench and get following error to MySQL running on AWS EC2, Amazon Linux AMI:

Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 through SSH tunnel at ec2......eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22 with user root

Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: MySQL Workbench settings for MySQL hosted on Amazon Web Services EC2]

The trick was to use the ec2-user for the ssh username, not root. Attached image shows an example of the settings.

Comment: Yes. And if you're using ubuntu, the default user is ubuntu. Amazon images come with a rule to deny root from connecting via ssh.